# Device Not Ready (Firmware missing)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ubuntu-drivers, realtek-wireless

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in network menu shown:

> Device Not Ready (Firmware missing).

Please help me to get work my pc's wireless adapter.

When i run `lspci -v` it shows

```
09:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    DeviceName:  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b2510000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci, rt3290sta

09:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at b2500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Install firmwares package

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
  ```

  Then reboot, see if works.
- If It didn't work, blacklist the `rt2800pci` module

  ```
  echo "blacklist rt2800pci" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-myrt2800pci.conf
  ```

  Then reboot.